# Measurability preserved under limit

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $(f_n)_n$ be a sequence converging to $f$ in $L^p(\Omega,\mathfrak{F},\mu)$ for some $1\leq p\leq\infty$. Assume all the $f_n$ are measurable with respect to $\mathfrak{G}\subset\mathfrak{F}$. Does this imply that $f$ is measurable with respect to $\mathfrak{G}$?

I think if I am working with a probability space (or a finite measure space) $(\Omega,\mathfrak{F},\mu)$ I can prove that the limit is again measurable with respect to $\mathfrak{G}$ using conditional expectations. Is there any way to conclude something similar for non-finite measure spaces?

Comment: Finiteness is not needed. True in general.

Comment: Just restrict yuor attention to $(\Omega, \mathfrak{G})$ and use the standard fact that limits of meausrable functions are measurable.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I know measurability is preserved under pointwise limits, I have limits in $L^p$. How do you prove it in the general case?

Comment: Convergence in $L^{p}$ implies a.e. convergence for  as subsequence.

Comment: Yet the "almost everywhere" is with respect to nullsets in $\mathfrak{F}$. I need to either assume that these nullsets are also included in $\mathfrak{G}$ or be content with a statement like "$f$ is almost everywhere equal to a function that is measurable with respect to $\mathfrak{G}$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the a.e. pointwise limit of a sequence of measurable function is measurable. The proof is quite straightforward. Since you are working with a complete measure space, every null set is measurable. If you call $\Omega_0$ the null set where you don't have pointwise convergence and $f$ the a.e. pointwise limit, the measurability of $f$ is equivalent to the measurability of $f|_{\Omega \setminus \Omega_0}$, and now it's easy because the pointwise limit of a sequence of measurable functions is measurable. You can find the proof with all the details, for example, in Royden, Fitzpatrick "Real Analysis"

Comment: Thank you. I did not assume that the measure space was complete in my question, yet I see how it is relevant and that the statement won't hold true if the space is not complete (or even if $\mathfrak{G}$ does not contain a nullset that is contained in $\mathfrak{F}$).

Comment: Oh yeah, completeness of the space here is absolutely crucial. You can find counterexamples otherwise

Comment: I mean, it's really straightforward. Take a sequence of constant functions (say they are constantly 1). Then take a function that is 1 everywhere except on a non measurable null set. There you have your counterexample

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. Thanks.